# C piping, how to make child tell "im waiting for stdin" to parent waiting for child to finish

Tags: c, pipe, fork, deadlock, execvp

One time I have parent executing `grep` and child executing `ls -la` in pipe like `ls -la | grep something`, and its working as requested. Parent waits for child to finish. But now in opposite case parent is executing `ls -la` and child `grep`. Parent wait for child to finish and child wait for stdin. How to avoid deadlock? Should I execute them in parallel and save output to buffer. How to do it when execution is by execvp?

Comment: The normal way is to create *two* child processes, one for each command, and set up the pipe between them. Then the parent process waits for *both* children.

Comment: Usually, you aren't closing enough file descriptors. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: You should always execute all the processes in a pipeline in parallel.  If you have process A piping data to process B, and A produces enough data to fill the pipe buffer (usually 64 KiB these days; it was less in times past), then it will block waiting for a process to read the pipe (B).  If the process that should read the pipe (B) isn't running but is waiting for A to finish, you have a deadlock.  Don't create that deadlock; do run A and B concurrently.